# How should I connect the power?

Tags: power, power-supply, power-management

I have a B+ connected to a H-bridge which is connected to 4 AA batteries and 4 motors, and they work fine, but now I want to add a distance sensor, which requires 5v, so do I need any extra batteries?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 5v output on the gpios of the Raspberry Pi. However be **careful**, you mustn't connect the *echo* pin directly to the gpio. Instead you can make a voltage divider on the wire connecting the *echo* pin because the b+ can't handle anything over 3.3v. Not using a voltage divider *will* damage your Raspberry Pi.

You can use a 470 Ohm and a 1K Ohm resistor with the 1K connecting *echo* and ground. Refer to the diagram below if you are unsure.
[image]

Comment: My tutorial just uses just a 1 kilo ohm resistor, is that okay?

Comment: @Vedbot It is risky, I can't guarantee the voltage will be around 3.3v without a voltage divider. Maybe someone else can tell you.

Comment: The official line has always been that any current at a voltage greater than 3.3V will eventually kill the GPIO/Pi.  I can't see the official line changing.  A voltage divider is safest.  If you can only use 1 resistor I suggest a value of 10k or more.